# Call function in external .js file from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Hey I've got a Nodejs file running on Heroku and I want to call various functions in an external file, but I'm not sure how to do it.

My external tool.js file looks like this:

```
var Tool = {}; //tool namespace
Tool.doSomething =  function(a,b){}
Tool.doSomethingElse = function(a,b){}
```

How do I export this functionality to available in my nodejs file?

Presumably in my nodejs file I have something like:

```
import nodeTool = require('./tool.js');
```

Then I'd like to call it like:

```
var n = nodeTool.doSomething(a,b);
```

Any help is appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

tool.js

```
exports.doSomething = function(a,b){}
exports.doSomethingElse = function(a,b){}
```

node file:

```
var nodeTool = require('./tool.js')
var n = nodeTool.doSomething(a,b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but what about the namespace? If I change Tool.doSomething to exports.doSomething I think bad things will happen.

Comment: This is an explanation for this approach: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/